# How to restart MAIN activity

Tags: android, android-activity, restart

I need the content on the MAIN activity to be updated when a child activity returns. i tried the following code inside the `onActivityResult()` method which works fine for other activities (non-MAIN) but not for MAIN activity.

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
    finish();
    startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

Any ideas on how to make the MAIN activity execute the OnCreate() again?

Thanks!

Comment: you can simply call onCreate(null)

Comment: revert their order: startActivity() and then finish()

Comment: your code is right!! i am afraid you are not reaching in resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK block put logs and see.

Comment: what exactly you want, to call OnActivityResult() or onCreate()

Comment: Reversing the order did not work. I verified that it is reaching the code, but suspect that the activity is MAIN so it behaves differently. I'm not sure if calling onCreate(null) is right because somewhere I read that it could break other things. I'll try it anyways. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

write the thing on OnResume () method..it will execute always when u return back to main activity..for details go through activity life cycle..

Comment: Moving the code shown in the question to onResume() is disastrous, as the app cannot even start in case of calling finish() at the last, and onCreate() is not called in case of calling finish() first. Also, I wanted to refresh the activity only in case of child activity returning OK result, and not for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to that the `setResult()` is ignored if the current activity is restarted. See my [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043239/setresult-does-not-work-after-activitiy-is-restarted).

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourMainActivity.this, YourMainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code inside `onBackPressed()` method:

```java
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Where `MainActivity.class` is my launcher Activity.
Now the activity will return to the same content it launches every time.

Comment: This does not address the actual question - they are not attempting to specifically handle back presses.