# setResult() does not work after activitiy is restarted

Tags: android, android-activity, restart

I have three activities A, B and C.

A starts B with `startActivityForResult(getIntent(), ACTIVITY_B);` and B starts C with `startActivityForResult(getIntent(), ACTIVITY_C);`. `ACTIVITY_B` and `ACTIVITY_C` are constants with same value across activities.

When C returns with RESULT_OK, then B is restarted with the code:

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
    finish();
    startActivityForResult(getIntent(), ACTIVITY_B);
}
```

This works fine.

When B has to return (on clicking a menu item), it sets the activity result.

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_CONFIRM:
            System.out.println("Setting Result to RESULT_OK");
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

However I can see that the `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);` is ignored because it is always received as `RESULT_CANCEL` in the Activity A (`onActivityResult`). I'm using 2.3.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't finish B and start a new one, A will not get notified because it's not the B it opened. 
Instead, if C needs to return something to B when it ends, create an Intent, put your result values on it, and check this result in B:

C:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
// Store values you want to return on the intent
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

B: in onActivityResult

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
  // get values from the intent and change B accordingly
}
```

Comment: Yep. Just figured the issue as you mentioned. It is not the same B which was started by A. I'm fixing this by a different solution which should work for me - I have moved my UI update code into onResume() method with no need to restart B. Still testing it. Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious how you are handling your Intents and Activity lifecycle.

From what I have read in both of your posts:

- A starts B with startActivityForResult().
- B starts C with startActivityForResult().
- C completes its task, calls setResult() and finish().

Now unless there is something I am missing, Activity B uses this code:

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
    finish();
    startActivityForResult(getIntent(), ACTIVITY_B);
}
```

to start itself? Could you clarify this?

**Addition**

I believe you are starting B from B so when you call setResult() and finish() in your second instance of B you are returning to the first B Activity.

If you are not using any special Intent flags the lifecycle will be:

- A starts B

  - B starts C

    - C finishes
  - B resumes automatically, B finishes
- A resumes automatically.

From what I understand you have altered that cycle to:

- A starts B

  - B starts C

    - C finishes
  - B resumes automatically, onActivityResult() starts 2nd B

    - 2nd B finishes, (You expect to see A next, however...)
  - B resumes automatically (If you call finish() again you should see A at this point).

  ...
- A is waiting in the stack to be resumed.

Comment: I need to restart B because its content needs to be updated when C finishes with RESULT_OK. I don't think the second flow you have mentioned mentioned is what is happening, because when 2nd B starts, the 1st is already finished. I think you missed the finishing of 1st B. So when 2nd B finishes, I expect it to return to A which should see the result as RESULT_OK.

Comment: Also, If, C is not started, all this is working as expected. That is, B returns and A gets RESULT_OK. It is only when C is called, and B is restarted, then the setResult() statement is ignored. I get sysout, indicating the code is being executed but has no effect.

Comment: Is this code block from above `if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {...}` in Activity B's onActivityResult()?